# Automatic package management corrupted - binary output?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I am running Ubuntu Bionic. When I try to install something via apt-get, I get a long error with binary outputs:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bridge-utils ubuntu-fan
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 321 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 252 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_AU.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_AU.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 176441 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-fan (0.12.10) ...
ubuntu-fan: removing default /etc/network/fan configuration
Removing bridge-utils (1.5-15ubuntu1) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (4.15.0-46.49) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 1: 07070100000065000041ED0000000000000000000000025B07FAC000000000000000030000000100000000000000000000000700000000kernel07070100000066000041ED0000000000000000000000025B07FAC000000000000000030000000100000000000000000000000B00000000kernel/x8607070100000067000041ED0000000000000000000000025B07FAC000000000000000030000000100000000000000000000001500000000kernel/x86/microcode07070100000068000041ED0000000000000000000000025B07FAC000000000000000030000000100000000000000000000003600000000kernel/x86/microcode/.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc07070100000069000081A40000000000000000000000015B07FAC000180C00000000030000000100000000000000000000002600000000kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 1: ?ɗ??$?8?: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 1: $'\276M\327\253\035\240\336\377\272IW!\257\316OsS\263\371\216\203ʰ\320': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 2: $'R\300\251\3421^\331\375ɟ\220\202\222,\235t\320@\037\004\356Eq\356X\213M\230,a\251\2079\315\341\205,\230\270\211\213K\315\f~?A\227\300a\373': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 2: $'\242,\024Py\266\264\001\353\223y$\273w': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'\317\025\030\244\0348\205\3042\213': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'\255\v#\376ߏ': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: ^?: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: `
                                                                    ??CL
                                                                        6Ǩrq)Ym??#}|???$rt#?0D(?l?????5!T???hW?q?q̼3P???l??7    >?'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'\317\025\030\244\0348\205\3042\213': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'\255\v#\376ߏ': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: ^?: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: `
                                                                    ??CL
                                                                        6Ǩrq)Ym??#}|???$rt#?0????Q?*??P۠̂?e? ???I?ó?E? ۜY?.L?E9G???g???E?u:????'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: `ȗhF0???y4+??{,??V?Рrr?t?k@??j?
                                                                                                    ???
                                                                                                           ؄???q?=Fi???L??Λ??1df??g?1{+?.??"z"GZU]Q????A??ژ:Y|??H)֮?(?????i?G???$???&?#Ȱ?5q?|?,ࡲ???z?L?b??$-??I7tN?h
 ???#?|?ޙ?q??E:?b?
                  2????q?????f???a?f:???4?d?1n'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'*\027h\227\355\E': command not found
Bn?B?N?2!3??F#s??Zӝ?h?$?????4??۝?;?9?ڗ~-?A??-?0ں????J?S\??[?H?/?؃?,?9!?KA??-Wg/;rjLL?ɯ?M鸧? 5ͪP~??????ħ? ??&\???v?8f??
d?
͖??GޤJ?*???^??????ox#8??\*ݚ??7?yk?-ן?j&y????#??sl??2????k?N??bHV?f
?\?]????????-A??6@6??j?鱈?xW??|#,??W?????wK????sM?tT??;/????l?B9???1?'?y??dqf????Lmi>?p?T?q؍z?R??????*?4??%???U?[ZL?^?lҰˠ????p]?x?L?Q]??S0?$?d?/???(?8?r ??E??|K;p?r/????MU??H0D
                                    ???觑
                                         ?K&????}??v*???+?
?i???? ?˿)
??%??P?P???u?z?y?????p?E25
$?????z??s?
l?rPA3???j? n?r?T?jZ߈?PiEbU)?ɭ??\?v?3'??3?l?b???Ѡ??E?0\'????????,?:nx?o?S?y??mM?A%p
                         HR?
                            Q: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'{\234:\EhWW\b:H\257\200\240\003\224': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $']\004\001C\262{\361j+i': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: `;?5??????   pAWI???H?]գ?)?X!?p!FԋR?:{??YL???cGE??{?p?\f,)??=?{??C???%??^??4-?m<?????????'?osi???~????|7?x?NK????ޘ'?? O**?B?s
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: `l?X9a????Ռ?????O'3?U?M?c??BtJ??d?|???.???1?ƉHcT?>???h??1.011i?l??É?L3Cb?k?0??V?,?!?<S??:p?~??)??Tݮ?vq+?~
?-??G?c#?('S?)??\S:?s??~???d?eߛ???&?{?޳?TL?em?d?F??|?m?_???2)??svԊK?>,@??~!?????.?(i?(?ȏN.K???ݘO?
X,-u?+?#?~T]!??T?d<?M)%z????q?P}?;?u??x??R{ß??v?q[)M!X4,????A?d???B?ND?2?GB?5~J3C?P??";v7h?T.?3?Ua??/N?B|?d?휯?˥?-XX??]p?Y?R??E?????\?H?] ?s?????-?E?
        ??O?z?7??pBo5Ȣ?S???F?t?/g6?L&?R?!?)??G?v.
                                                 )???????Q??6???\????
                                                                     "??Y????'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: `???R????S2_?]?z#??????]*5W?Į?'/??a??D?჏?F1?c9"??E?G5??\y]!??#???Jc?n?uq??@?d?6l"??E5?'?q'???y?Ȓ??n??????=??J?7?R6??dG?a?w;r???e?3WD'/??4??jD??p
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'\227\204\242\027R\273\020\370\224\241\210\267D\330\375iuQ\341\260Cgr\372\344Ǻ\244\363\335\332\342W\006\267': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'暀\234': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: ??e??3?{??U3PM?W[4h?@??W?[?z??]?b????Zh??a8$d???;(sj?1n??hKwdNO?&L??~@?HN?????X2?/Ϡ?2+i꺚`?????)?0KQĒNt)?NB
S+?4?p{?[?KA???????C??#S?0??x?(|?D?W?.M?? N????0k/??d?tl91dʞ    @?1 ??l
Տ??J??m??pShx?]};?ttwe?Q?OE???P??r?]ľ?
                                      uc?3???f?׽4y??a?l??U?G9?6z?b]?J?????ɇ@?,?F#s](??9!?????O???՜?6?
                                                                                                      ?[~???J?ن??ufbb?H8%?΀\??0???e51????|m?+u??=????zDD
?4-?m<?????????`??WI???H?]գ?)?X!?p!FԋR?:{??YL???cGE??{?p?\f,)??=?{??C???%??^???u?6?Z?pr0B0=?r?osi???~????|7?x?NK????ޘ'?? O**?B?s
3/???i???`l?X9a????Ռ?????O'3?U?M?c??BtJ??d?|???.???1?ƉHcT?>???h??1.011i?l??É?L3Cb?k?0??V?,?!?<S??:p?~??)??Tݮ?vq+?~YV??a??;o\oNXG?N?!???_{3?J?
?-??G?c#?('S?)??\S:?s??~???d?eߛ???&?{?޳?TL?em?d?F??|?m?_???2)??svԊK?>,@??~!?????.?(i?(?ȏN.K???ݘO?               ?0.?%@??:e?SϏ?
X,-u?+?#?~T]!??T?d<?M)%z????q?P}?;?u??x??R{ß??v?q[)M!X4,????A?d???B?ND?2?GB?5~J3C?P??";v7h?T.?3?Ua??/N?B|?d?휯?˥?-XX??]p?Y?R??E?????\\?H?] ?s?????-?E?
         ??O?z?7??pBo5Ȣ?S???F?t?/g6?L&?R?!?)??G?v.
                                                  )???????Q??6???\????
                                                                      "??Y????
o?~??c?z?H?hIy??odV_??к?>? ????7Щ?????
??l?5?h??s???
             d?d?C~?????@????r]7?\P$؝?3?.?$>b]?`%????f?`ڥ????ϙ?!&?>
                                                                     ??"?a??'N\??0?O?q?Tuq??WDS?Юe?&?&?E??&????;??S?VQ?o
                                                                                                                        ?n????c3?eZx?t? -?_?o?ۓ6?)RJ?M?j?
???R????S2_?]?z#??????]*5W?Į?'/??a??D?჏?F1?c9"??E?G5??\y]!??#???Jc?n?uq??????[om?]?^;??Z???M??9_   ??a?.?p??ǅ&Ⱬ???s?????????x?2σ?????.JY@?d?6l"??E5???q'???y?Ȓ??n??????=??J?7?R6??dG?a?w;r???e?3WD'/??4??jD??p

???Bt?Ql?UU?Jc  ???I8"R?'??^;K?B???[?U?k?l
\??a
    ?
m/s???|Mr?s?d?e?_s?)
?,?0|5????{
           ??{X@??e??M/^#n??Iыe???r??Ad@i_?z??? ??r?i?<???꡶IZX?h@????3?.?zl??o?ۍ?\ ?L?K?87Xn???3
                                                                                                ?R??=???h??DdG?a?"n'?ʨ0Į?rz??4????|ڧ?1?c9?\b?5?
?   ??g??#??&?? ???mwL[?om?]?Q
                                      nK?B?\?3?j???9_   'D8?
                                                            ?
                                                             ????ЌH????k?d?e?
&?|_?y2σʵ??P?{

              ???E[???z??=?Iы?Np?U??j??ꖠL????u??/??n?ѳ?5!]vN??÷+!R?Q??IC8z?6qK????^?ݮ?P4(߉???$?!/???z   tzmV??g???J???X??4??~(&??:?ˮv??t??}??{lƗb?է?}[̷?%e?n?ۿr?2C?????3?jqR H0?[YC??> ????0?ܔ???5Yy?@?*KOԢB{???O:??
W?ׯ???+? ???5z2I???}? ??-?m?xh??x?W*?z"+?`='?l???????>?8c@?`???R??????D??iuQ?Cgr??Ǻ?????W?;暀? 
?A???9#??3?6g??_?344?b?-?^?d?!??jO?Q?Jcԝ+???h??"k?Zqf??V?????G???\r???n?;??''1čZ1? ?%??O??`???6xL???k??{N??dT[D???e???%??$?\? 뙅K????g(t??Ù????}?һ ????P?H6dS??W??!?b??Gt?t?: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 25: $'\026\321': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 26: $'S5M\307\350\257\024vi\2566\3019': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 26: $'?z\023\273ީ': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 26: $'\351\346\254\353x\200\301\276d\250\216\234\021[\366\261\340\346\2571=y': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 29: $'9\257\2779\371C\314\326Q\340\275': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 29: $'4\256': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 31: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 32: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 29: ?i?M?r?e?????RV,???O
                                                                 xٞȥ??: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 29: $'\247q\355\333\3604sg\241i\345\f\034\030\371\212\215X\3123': command not found
???˨!rm?߮䀷??ɍ????#?D)??S??uݔ?? O?ߐP]??Q?f?Ꮏ[:??ߢ???ҧ??|)?c:??`X?9?4???ޣ?q*W??0C???#ԩ??Qe\??yJ?O[$?l?F??
??-6~?m)gtrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 30: `???O)??P?u?????y??W???P??Ocr?۽l????T??斛?=??t?N?N??qE??{- i ????̊???g???7???7U?8R??@?nC^.?8??U????4??w???  gR???jQ????'
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (4.15.0-46.49) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 1: 07070100000065000041ED0000000000000000000000025B07FAC000000000000000030000000100000000000000000000000700000000kernel07070100000066000041ED0000000000000000000000025B07FAC000000000000000030000000100000000000000000000000B00000000kernel/x8607070100000067000041ED0000000000000000000000025B07FAC000000000000000030000000100000000000000000000001500000000kernel/x86/microcode07070100000068000041ED0000000000000000000000025B07FAC000000000000000030000000100000000000000000000003600000000kernel/x86/microcode/.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc07070100000069000081A40000000000000000000000015B07FAC000180C00000000030000000100000000000000000000002600000000kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 1: $'\276M\327\253\035\240\336\377\272IW!\257\316OsS\263\371\216\203ʰ\320': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 1: ?ɗ??$?8?: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 2: $'R\300\251\3421^\331\375ɟ\220\202\222,\235t\320@\037\004\356Eq\356X\213M\230,a\251\2079\315\341\205,\230\270\211\213K\315\f~?A\227\300a\373': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 2: $'\242,\024Py\266\264\001\353\223y$\273w': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'\317\025\030\244\0348\205\3042\213': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'\255\v#\376ߏ': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: ^?: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: `
                                                                    ??CL
                                                                        6Ǩrq)Ym??#}|???$rt#?0D(?l?????5!T???hW?q?q̼3P???l??7    >?'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'\317\025\030\244\0348\205\3042\213': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'\255\v#\376ߏ': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: ^?: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: `
                                                                    ??CL
                                                                        6Ǩrq)Ym??#}|???$rt#?0????Q?*??P۠̂?e? ???I?ó?E? ۜY?.L?E9G???g???E?u:????'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: `ȗhF0???y4+??{,??V?Рrr?t?k@??j?
                                                                                                    ???
                                                                                                           ؄???q?=Fi???L??Λ??1df??g?1{+?.??"z"GZU]Q????A??ژ:Y|??H)֮?(?????i?G???$???&?#Ȱ?5q?|?,ࡲ???z?L?b??$-??I7tN?h
 ???#?|?ޙ?q??E:?b?
                  2????q?????f???a?f:???4?d?1n'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'*\027h\227\355\E': command not found
Bn?B?N?2!3??F#s??Zӝ?h?$?????4??۝?;?9?ڗ~-?A??-?0ں????J?S\??[?H?/?؃?,?9!?KA??-Wg/;rjLL?ɯ?M鸧? 5ͪP~??????ħ? ??&\???v?8f??
d?
͖??GޤJ?*???^??????ox#8??\*ݚ??7?yk?-ן?j&y????#??sl??2????k?N??bHV?f
?\?]????????-A??6@6??j?鱈?xW??|#,??W?????wK????sM?tT??;/????l?B9???1?'?y??dqf????Lmi>?p?T?q؍z?R??????*?4??%???U?[ZL?^?lҰˠ????p]?x?L?Q]??S0?$?d?/???(?8?r ??E??|K;p?r/????MU??H0D
                                    ???觑
                                         ?K&????}??v*???+?
?i???? ?˿)
??%??P?P???u?z?y?????p?E25
$?????z??s?
l?rPA3???j? n?r?T?jZ߈?PiEbU)?ɭ??\?v?3'??3?l?b???Ѡ??E?0\'????????,?:nx?o?S?y??mM?A%p
                         HR?
                            Q: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $']\004\001C\262{\361j+i': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'{\234:\EhWW\b:H\257\200\240\003\224': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: `;?5??????   pAWI???H?]գ?)?X!?p!FԋR?:{??YL???cGE??{?p?\f,)??=?{??C???%??^??4-?m<?????????'?osi???~????|7?x?NK????ޘ'?? O**?B?s
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 13: `l?X9a????Ռ?????O'3?U?M?c??BtJ??d?|???.???1?ƉHcT?>???h??1.011i?l??É?L3Cb?k?0??V?,?!?<S??:p?~??)??Tݮ?vq+?~
?-??G?c#?('S?)??\S:?s??~???d?eߛ???&?{?޳?TL?em?d?F??|?m?_???2)??svԊK?>,@??~!?????.?(i?(?ȏN.K???ݘO?
X,-u?+?#?~T]!??T?d<?M)%z????q?P}?;?u??x??R{ß??v?q[)M!X4,????A?d???B?ND?2?GB?5~J3C?P??";v7h?T.?3?Ua??/N?B|?d?휯?˥?-XX??]p?Y?R??E?????\?H?] ?s?????-?E?
        ??O?z?7??pBo5Ȣ?S???F?t?/g6?L&?R?!?)??G?v.
                                                 )???????Q??6???\????
                                                                     "??Y????'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: `???R????S2_?]?z#??????]*5W?Į?'/??a??D?჏?F1?c9"??E?G5??\y]!??#???Jc?n?uq??@?d?6l"??E5?'?q'???y?Ȓ??n??????=??J?7?R6??dG?a?w;r???e?3WD'/??4??jD??p
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'\227\204\242\027R\273\020\370\224\241\210\267D\330\375iuQ\341\260Cgr\372\344Ǻ\244\363\335\332\342W\006\267': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: $'暀\234': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 14: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 13: ??e??3?{??U3PM?W[4h?@??W?[?z??]?b????Zh??a8$d???;(sj?1n??hKwdNO?&L??~@?HN?????X2?/Ϡ?2+i꺚`?????)?0KQĒNt)?NB
S+?4?p{?[?KA???????C??#S?0??x?(|?D?W?.M?? N????0k/??d?tl91dʞ    @?1 ??l
Տ??J??m??pShx?]};?ttwe?Q?OE???P??r?]ľ?
                                      uc?3???f?׽4y??a?l??U?G9?6z?b]?J?????ɇ@?,?F#s](??9!?????O???՜?6?
                                                                                                      ?[~???J?ن??ufbb?H8%?΀\??0???e51????|m?+u??=????zDD
?4-?m<?????????`??WI???H?]գ?)?X!?p!FԋR?:{??YL???cGE??{?p?\f,)??=?{??C???%??^???u?6?Z?pr0B0=?r?osi???~????|7?x?NK????ޘ'?? O**?B?s
3/???i???`l?X9a????Ռ?????O'3?U?M?c??BtJ??d?|???.???1?ƉHcT?>???h??1.011i?l??É?L3Cb?k?0??V?,?!?<S??:p?~??)??Tݮ?vq+?~YV??a??;o\oNXG?N?!???_{3?J?
?-??G?c#?('S?)??\S:?s??~???d?eߛ???&?{?޳?TL?em?d?F??|?m?_???2)??svԊK?>,@??~!?????.?(i?(?ȏN.K???ݘO?               ?0.?%@??:e?SϏ?
X,-u?+?#?~T]!??T?d<?M)%z????q?P}?;?u??x??R{ß??v?q[)M!X4,????A?d???B?ND?2?GB?5~J3C?P??";v7h?T.?3?Ua??/N?B|?d?휯?˥?-XX??]p?Y?R??E?????\\?H?] ?s?????-?E?
         ??O?z?7??pBo5Ȣ?S???F?t?/g6?L&?R?!?)??G?v.
                                                  )???????Q??6???\????
                                                                      "??Y????
o?~??c?z?H?hIy??odV_??к?>? ????7Щ?????
??l?5?h??s???
             d?d?C~?????@????r]7?\P$؝?3?.?$>b]?`%????f?`ڥ????ϙ?!&?>
                                                                     ??"?a??'N\??0?O?q?Tuq??WDS?Юe?&?&?E??&????;??S?VQ?o
                                                                                                                        ?n????c3?eZx?t? -?_?o?ۓ6?)RJ?M?j?
???R????S2_?]?z#??????]*5W?Į?'/??a??D?჏?F1?c9"??E?G5??\y]!??#???Jc?n?uq??????[om?]?^;??Z???M??9_   ??a?.?p??ǅ&Ⱬ???s?????????x?2σ?????.JY@?d?6l"??E5???q'???y?Ȓ??n??????=??J?7?R6??dG?a?w;r???e?3WD'/??4??jD??p

???Bt?Ql?UU?Jc  ???I8"R?'??^;K?B???[?U?k?l
\??a
    ?
m/s???|Mr?s?d?e?_s?)
?,?0|5????{
           ??{X@??e??M/^#n??Iыe???r??Ad@i_?z??? ??r?i?<???꡶IZX?h@????3?.?zl??o?ۍ?\ ?L?K?87Xn???3
                                                                                                ?R??=???h??DdG?a?"n'?ʨ0Į?rz??4????|ڧ?1?c9?\b?5?
?   ??g??#??&?? ???mwL[?om?]?Q
                                      nK?B?\?3?j???9_   'D8?
                                                            ?
                                                             ????ЌH????k?d?e?
&?|_?y2σʵ??P?{

              ???E[???z??=?Iы?Np?U??j??ꖠL????u??/??n?ѳ?5!]vN??÷+!R?Q??IC8z?6qK????^?ݮ?P4(߉???$?!/???z   tzmV??g???J???X??4??~(&??:?ˮv??t??}??{lƗb?է?}[̷?%e?n?ۿr?2C?????3?jqR H0?[YC??> ????0?ܔ???5Yy?@?*KOԢB{???O:??
W?ׯ???+? ???5z2I???}? ??-?m?xh??x?W*?z"+?`='?l???????>?8c@?`???R??????D??iuQ?Cgr??Ǻ?????W?;暀? 
?A???9#??3?6g??_?344?b?-?^?d?!??jO?Q?Jcԝ+???h??"k?Zqf??V?????G???\r???n?;??''1čZ1? ?%??O??`???6xL???k??{N??dT[D???e???%??$?\? 뙅K????g(t??Ù????}?һ ????P?H6dS??W??!?b??Gt?t?: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 25: $'\026\321': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 26: $'S5M\307\350\257\024vi\2566\3019': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 26: $'?z\023\273ީ': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 26: $'\351\346\254\353x\200\301\276d\250\216\234\021[\366\261\340\346\2571=y': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 29: $'9\257\2779\371C\314\326Q\340\275': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 29: $'4\256': command not found
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 31: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: command substitution: line 32: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 29: ?i?M?r?e?????RV,???O
                                                                 xٞȥ??: No such file or directory
/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 29: $'\247q\355\333\3604sg\241i\345\f\034\030\371\212\215X\3123': command not found
???˨!rm?߮䀷??ɍ????#?D)??S??uݔ?? O?ߐP]??Q?f?Ꮏ[:??ߢ???ҧ??|)?c:??`X?9?4???ޣ?q*W??0C???#ԩ??Qe\??yJ?O[$?l?F??
??-6~?m)gtrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic: line 30: `???O)??P?u?????y??W???P??Ocr?۽l????T??斛?=??t?N?N??qE??{- i ????̊???g???7???7U?8R??@?nC^.?8??U????4??w???  gR???jQ????'
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The same happens when installing, even when the package is already installed. What could be the reason behind this and is it related to the perl warnings at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Check what is in your /etc/default/locale
Seems like system has no idea what en_AU is.

The way that I can reproduce it:

```
root@x:/# LANG="en_US.UTF-8" perl -e exit

root@x:/# LANG="en_AU.UTF-8" perl -e exit
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_AU.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

You could try these:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
sudo locale-gen
```

Or change /etc/default/locale line where it says LANG to
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

Logout/login possibly needed after that.

Comment: I changed the language to US by reconfigure. Now, in my locale file I have only LANG=en_US.UTF-8. Still, the error is the same, even after logout.

Comment: But your advice fixed the warnings about the language, which were unrelated to the main problem, but still I learned something! Thanks!